# grails-plugin-publish unavailable in grails 4.0.11?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-4

I'm attempting to upgrade a grails plugin from grails version `4.0.3` to `4.0.11` and get the following error immediately after changing the grails and GORM versions:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-plugin-project'.
> Plugin with id 'org.grails.grails-plugin-publish' not found.
```

I get this same error in a new project generated from `grails create-plugin` as well, so I don't think it's something I'm doing inherently wrong.

This appears to be a bug in `4.0.11` as upgrading to `4.0.10` seems to load fine.

Comment: That looks like a bug.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can investigate.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I see the same behavior if I create a new 4.0.11 app.

Comment: Thanks, posted issue 12007

Comment: Following up here from the bug thread - this plugin was removed and was errantly left in new projects, though not documented in the grails upgrade guide, the path to replacing the removed plugin is documented here - https://grails.org/blog/2021-04-07-publish-grails-plugin-to-maven-central.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> grails-plugin-publish unavailable in grails 4.0.11?

Right, it is not available in 4.0.11.

That was intentional as it is no longer needed.  However, there is a bug in that newly created plugin projects created with 4.0.11 still express a dependency on it.  That is simple enough to remedy by just deleting the line of code that applies the plugin, but we will be fixing the project generation so that isn't necessary.  Leaving it there was just an accident.

See [github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12007](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12007).